# Why line_solid does not appear?

Tags: android, android-layout, line

Why when the line_solid does not appear? It worked with line_dotted

```xml
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:src="@drawable/line_solid"
    android:layerType="software"
    android:tint="@color/color_primary_variant"
    android:layout_marginTop ="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"                    
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_app_description"/>
```

Comment: Can you specify your requirement ? I mean you want full image as dotted line or dotted border over imageview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer 
I needed to change the tag from `- android:tint= ..` to `- android:background= ..`

Thanks a lot for the inspirations :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this. It is provide line.

```
   <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
```

Comment: @Muss Mesmari  I'm glad for you. :)